# Is there a lens way to imap over all elements in a Map and possibly delete some?

Tags: haskell, dictionary, traversal, haskell-lens

Lens has [`imap`/`imapped`](http://ekmett.github.io/lens/Control-Lens-Indexed.html#v:imap), which can be used to modify elements of a `Data.Map` dependent on the index, but not delete elements.

It also has [`at`](http://ekmett.github.io/lens/Control-Lens-At.html#v:at), which can access / modify *and delete* a single element.

Is there a generic way to get the *combined* functionality, i.e. map over all element/index pairs and possibly delete some? It should be the operation that [`mapMaybeWithKey`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:mapMaybeWithKey) performs

```
mapMaybeWithKey :: (k -> a -> Maybe b) -> Map k a -> Map k b
```

but generalised in lens-language.

Comment: I'm not sure you can make a lawful (Indexed)Traversal that does that. I think it would have issues with the fusion law.  It'd need to be an `IndexedTraversal k (Map k a) (Map k b) a (Maybe b)`, and I have deep suspicions that type can't be made lawful.

Comment: You could lawfully implement something more like `IndexedTraversal k (Map k a) (Map k b) (Maybe a) (Maybe b)`.  But that would require enumerating all possible keys.  Still, that at least would clearly be lawful!